# Values are not getting inserted into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a NodeJS app, where I am using ExcelJS in one of the routes (powered by Express). In the following snippet, a simple loop is supposed to read rows from the Excel file, then insert them into the array. However, they don't seem to be inserting.

```
router.get('/work', function(req, res, next) {
    var posts = [];
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    workbook.xlsx.readFile(file).then(function() {
        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
        worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, function(row, rowNumber) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(row.values));
            posts.push(JSON.stringify(row.values));
        });
    });
    res.json(posts);
});
```

That `console.log` line works just fine, as I am able to see the values in the console as they are logged. However, the values just don't get inserted into the `posts` array for some reason. Any one know why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this operation is asynchronous, you need to send your array back after you have completed reading your CSV:

```
router.get('/work', function(req, res, next) {
    var posts = [];
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    workbook.xlsx.readFile(file).then(function() {
        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
        worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, function(row, rowNumber) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(row.values));
            posts.push(JSON.stringify(row.values));
        });
        res.json(posts); // moved within the callback to `then`
    });
});
```

Before, you were immediately terminating the request with your empty array, before the promise returned by `readFile` resolved and allowed you to fill it with the values from your CSV.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I am unsure what you changed in the code above. It seems to be identical to mine. If that was done on purpose, could you please give an example of what you are suggesting?

Comment: @DemCodeLines it isn't identical but definitely hard to determine visually. I've added a comment that (hopefully) clarifies things

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now.